# User can't list directory even with correct permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I've been trying to enter a directory with a user named `user` which is in the group `user`.
The directory is named `the_forbidden_one` and is owned by the user `the_chosen_one` and the group `the_chosen_ones`. Even if my directory has `r-x` permissions for the "others", `user` can't list or even enter the directory. Why?

```
ls -la:
drwxrwxr-x 13 the_chosen_one the_chosen_ones 4096 Oct 15 12:10 the_forbidden_one
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what are the permissions on the higher level directories, above the current one.  if anyone of them is not x for other then your user will not be able to descend past that point in the directory tree.

Comment: I thought you only needed `x` for _enumerating_ folders, rather than reading files therein (so long as you know their name)?